# How can I delete lines that has an empty first column?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

INPUT:

```
CC2352345|m,safnlasndfmnyxdcvyxcvyxcv             |klasjdf |3|lasdjflasdf|                    |2345567356
CC3543353|asdfasdffghntz                          |klasjdf |3|lsajdfl |                       |3456561235
CC5634554|asfjmklasdfassasdasasdsdfas             |klasjdf |3|lsajdfl |                       |2345635636
     |masdfjklasdfjasldfjlasjdfklas|          | |       |                       |2345234566
CC4723456|asdjkfasjkldfjaklsjdflkajldkfjlasjdflk  |klasjdf |2|lsajdfl |                       |2345234525
DD3455463|asldfklklfaem,.rtklqerktljekltjklqe     |klasjdf |3|lsajdfl |                       |4565467546
```

OUTPUT:

```
CC2352345|m,safnlasndfmnyxdcvyxcvyxcv             |klasjdf |3|lasdjflasdf|                    |2345567356
CC3543353|asdfasdffghntz                          |klasjdf |3|lsajdfl |                       |3456561235
CC5634554|asfjmklasdfassasdasasdsdfas             |klasjdf |3|lsajdfl |                       |2345635636
CC4723456|asdjkfasjkldfjaklsjdflkajldkfjlasjdflk  |klasjdf |2|lsajdfl |                       |2345234525
DD3455463|asldfklklfaem,.rtklqerktljekltjklqe     |klasjdf |3|lsajdfl |                       |4565467546
```

QUESTION: How can I delete lines that has an empty first column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
sed '/^\s\s*/d' file
```

Or even:

```
grep -v '^\s' file
```

Comment: How about `/^\s*|/d`?

Comment: You can do it any way you'd like. I can write another ten solutions for that like `sed -n '/^\S/p'`. But does it matter?

Comment: You should be asking the OP whether it matters, not me.  I'm just here to point out that the `/^\s\s*/d` will let lines like `|...` slip through whereas `/^\s*|/d` will not.

Comment: Hm.. Yeap you're right. So thank you for your comment and explanation (: At the first time I thought there is no difference in output between your and mine regexes. But there is. And now I see it.

Answer (score 1):

How about `awk`, because it hasn't been mentioned?

```
awk -F\| '$1~/\w/' file
```

Comment: Note that `\w` is specific to `gawk`. You could write more portably: `awk -F '[ \t]*\\|' '$1 != ""' file`

Comment: `awk -F\| '$1!~/^ *$/'`